# How do you calculate T(n) in an equation from a code fragment?

Tags: java, time-complexity, big-o, discrete-mathematics

I'm having trouble converting code fragments into equations that figure out T(n) of said equation. An example code fragment is this:

a = b + c;
d = a + e;

This specific questions asks to determine T(n). How would I go about doing that? Another example code given is as follows:

```
sum = 0;
for (i=0; i<3; i++)
    for (j=0; j<n; j++)
        sum++;
```

I've attempted to follow instruction and examples from other questions that are similar, but am getting stuck on how the equation is found exactly. Here's an example and result that I know of so far:

Code:

```
sum = 0;
i = 1;
while (i <= N)
{
    sum = sum + 1;
    i++;
}
```

With the result being this:
T(N) = 2 + (Σ with N on top and i+1 on bottom) * 2
and that ends up simplifying to 2+2N
I'm unsure of how this result is found though.

Comment: When you say you want to determine T(n), does that mean you want to calculate time complexity of the given code?

Comment: Yes, sorry for not clarifying in the post. I think that's what the question is looking for. @AleksaMajkic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can approach this problem:

```
sum = 0;                 // 1 - O(1)
for (i=0; i<3; i++)      // This will run 3x times - O(3)
    for (j=0; j<n; j++)  // This will run n times (O(n)), meaning the sum will be increased n times 
        sum++;
```

Then you can write `T(n)=1+3*(1+n+2n)≈1+3n`. This means that the time complexity for this code is O(n).

Generally, when looking at the simple `for` loop, like the one here, you can determine its complexity by looking at the condition statement. For `j<n` the complexity will be O(n), and for `i<3` the complexity will be O(3).